# how to call or execute azure cli commands programmatically from .Net/C# or PowerShell?

Tags: .net, powershell, azure, azure-cli

I am trying to execute azure CLI commands pro-grammatically from .NET/C# or PowerShell. But i couldn't find any approach to run this. Can someone throw light on this ?

Answer (score 3):

Azure CLI is a **command line interface** so you can use it in PowerShell similar if you are in the command line. In .NET / C# you have to invoke it by starting a new process - take a look at `System.Diagnostics.Process`.

However, you should consider using the [AzureSDK for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/) or using the REST API.

Comment: Well, I would like to execute Azure CLI file/command from PowerShell or C# by passing parameters - I couldn't find any Azure CLI comands equivalent in PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure PowerShell for any azure automation. After installing Azure PowerShell you can create powershell script to create/start/stop VMs and many more other requirements.

Commands to start or stop azure VM with powershell.

```
start-AzureVM -ServiceName $($entry.SERVICE) -Name $($entry.VM) 
start-AzureVM -ServiceName $ServiceName -Name $Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, that would allow you to do things in C#, is to use the [Azure REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/).  It's definitely a **lot** more work digging through the documentation trying to find the URIs you are after, but for the hardcore C# folks out there, it may be the answer they are after.

Comment: I've done this from Java.  While it's doable, be forewarned that MS's documentation is poor, and good examples are far and few between.